# Monitoring Web Server Internet Connection

Tags: curl, monitoring, zabbix

I would like to monitor my internet connection using zabbix 5.2.3 (anoher tool can be used), I mean that I would like to monitor if my host can reach google web site or not (for example, I would like to check if in 3 minutes I can't reach [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) for at lest 5 times and so, system will fire me an alert)... in order to do that, I think to set up a trigger like that:

```
{www.google.com:icmpping.count(3m,0)}>5
```

When I try to insert the expression above to set up a trigger, I get the following message

Incorrect trigger expression. Host "www.google.com" does not exist or you have no access to this host.

Is there any other way to monitor if my server can reach or not any url address?

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , or possibly [unix.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: what he said, and you need to create an host with google.com as DNS name